# hyperrefとpdfcommentのくみあわせ

Tags: latex

[hyperrefパッケージ](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)の提供するリンク機能（`\hyperref`コマンド）と、[pdfcommentパッケージ](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment)の提供するtooltip機能（`\pdftooltip`コマンド）を組み合わせると、後者の機能が失われる問題に遭遇しています。次のTeXドキュメントで検証しています:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}\label{sec:hw}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item\pdftooltip{it works}{this is tooltip text}
  \item\ref{sec:hw}
  \item\hyperref[sec:hw]{click here}
  \item\pdftooltip{\hyperref[sec:hw]{click here}}{this is tooltip text}
  \item\hyperref[sec:hw]{\pdftooltip{click here}{this is tooltip text}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

このうち、実現したいのは4,5番目の項目のような使い方ですが、コンパイルはできるものの機能していないように見えます。解決する方法はなにかないでしょうか。

環境:
- `This is e-pTeX, Version 3.14159265-p3.8.2-190131-2.6 (utf8.euc) (TeX Live 2019/Cygwin) (preloaded format=platex 2019.12.14)`
- `Package: hyperref 2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX`
- `Package: pdfcomment 2018/11/01 pdfcomment.sty v2.4a - Josef Kleber (C) 2008-2012, 2015-2016, 2018`
- `This is dvipdfmx Version 20190225 by the DVIPDFMx project team, modified for TeX Live, an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.`
- viewer: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Product Version 19.21.20058.359605

同等な結果が得られればこれらのパッケージ・コンパイラにこだわりません。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解決にはなりませんが Twitter で本件の調査が進んでいるようです。 https://twitter.com/zr_tex8r/status/1207284343455928321

Answer (score 0):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103628 を参考にいちおう動くものを見つけたので投稿しておきます。

`\hyperref`と`\pdftooltip`を組み合わせて使うと、PDFのマークアップ（？）が同じ領域に重複して出力されてしまうため、どちらかが（試した限りではリンクが）上に表示されてしまい、質問で挙げたような問題になるのだと考えられます。そこで、link annot.にtooltipをくっつける、または、widget annot.にリンクをくっつける、のいずれかができれば解決しそうです。前者は仕様に存在しないようなので、後者を実験したコードが以下になります:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{hyperref@tooltip}
\def\hyperrefWithTooltip[#1]#2#3{\begingroup%
  \let\hyper@link\hyper@link@insert@tooltip%
  \def\tooltip@content{#3}%
  \hyperref[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup}
\def\hyper@link@insert@tooltip#1#2#3{%
  \Hy@VerboseLinkStart{#1}{#2}%
  \ltx@IfUndefined{@#1bordercolor}{%
    \let\Hy@tempcolor\relax%
  }{%
    \edef\Hy@tempcolor{\csname @#1bordercolor\endcsname}%
  }%
  \begingroup%
    \protected@edef\Hy@testname{#2}%
    \ifx\Hy@testname\@empty%
      \Hy@Warning{Empty destination name,%
        \MessageBreak using `\Hy@undefinedname '}
      \let\Hy@testname\Hy@undefinedname%
    \fi%
    \pdfmark[{#3}]{%
      Color=\Hy@tempcolor,%
      linktype={#1},%
      AcroHighlight=\@pdfhighlight,%
      Border=\@pdfborder,%
      BorderStyle=\@pdfborderstyle,%
      pdfmark=/ANN,%
      %Subtype=/Link,%
      Subtype=/Widget,%
      Raw={%
        /TU (\tooltip@content)%
        /T (tooltip.\thehyperref@tooltip)%
        /C [ ]%
        /FT/Btn%
        /F 768%
        /Ff 65536%
        /H/N%
        /BS << /W 0 >>%
        %/A << /S/GoTo/D (\Hy@testname) >>% equiv.to.Dest
      },%
      PDFAFlags=4,%
      Dest=\Hy@testname}%
  \endgroup}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{hello world}\label{sec:hw}
\begin{itemize}
  \item hello \ref{sec:hw}
  \item \hyperref[sec:hw]{click here}
  \item \hyperrefWithTooltip[sec:hw]{click here}{this is tooltip text}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

これを`latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`でコンパイルすると、期待する結果を得られました。ただし、次の問題があります:

- `\hyperrefWithTooltip`ではリンクを表す枠が表示されない（動作に問題はない）
- Acrobat Reader以外ではtooltipが表示されない
- pdf.jsではリンクとして機能しない上にtooltipも表示されない

引き続き、よりよい解決策があれば提案していただけると幸いです。